# How to create a file (a text file as default if available) in python code

Tags: python, file, creation

This is the code I have so far, yes I know the 'dirs' code creates a folder, but I am not sure of the code (if there is one) to create a file instead!

```
import os
if os.path.isfile(outfile):
 print("Name already used, please choose another")
else:
 os.makedirs(outfile)
```

Any help would be appreciated :D

Comment: If you `open(filename, 'w')`, that will create a new file (or overwrite an existing one).

Comment: 1) Use 4-space indentation. 2) it is weird that `isfile(path) == False` implicates `makedirs(path)`. 3) Opening a file for writing creates the file if it does not exist yet. At least, this is how most operating systems behave, and this is how Python behaves on any supported platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inorder to create a file and work on it, use the `open()` function.

`fp = open(outfile, mode)`

modes:

r: read

w: if file exists, replace it with a new one

a: append existing file

In your case the mode is 'w'

Answer (score 0):

For create a file you can just open a file in write mode
`open('file.txt', 'w')`
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open